# Converting text into unordered, ordered or tables using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that is like chat website.

I want to automaticly detect lists and tables and format it into HTML code.

For example the given input

let text  = `1. Pizza2. Burgers3. Tacos4. Sushi5. Pasta6. Fried chicken7. Ramen8. Curry9. Steak10. Ice cream`; to convert this into Ordered list

let output = `<ol><li>Pizza</li><li>Burgers</li>...</ol>`;

and tables from this input

let text =  `| Rank | Game | |------|------------------------------| | 1 | The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt | | 2 | Grand Theft Auto V | | 3 | Portal 2 | | 4 | Half-Life 2 | | 5 | Overwatch | | 6 | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive | | 7 | Doom (2016) | | 8 | Dark Souls III | | 9 | Divinity: Original Sin II | | 10 | Stardew Valley |`;

into HTML code.

Note this should not remove any text before and after the list or tables, example

let input = "Hey look at the most popular video games for PC. 1.Minecraft 2.PUBG...." should not remove Hey look at the most popular video games for PC!!

I tried this code but sadly did not work

```
function convertTextToHTML(text) {
  const lines = text.split("\n");
  let result = "";
  let isTable = false;
  let isList = false;
  let tableHeaders = [];

  for (let line of lines) {
    if (line.startsWith("|") && line.endsWith("|")) {
      isTable = true;
      const cells = line.split("|").slice(1, -1);
      if (tableHeaders.length === 0) {
        tableHeaders = cells.map((cell) => `<th>${cell.trim()}</th>`);
        result += "<table><thead><tr>" + tableHeaders.join("") + "</tr></thead><tbody>";
      } else {
        const tableCells = cells.map((cell) => `<td>${cell.trim()}</td>`);
        result += "<tr>" + tableCells.join("") + "</tr>";
      }
    } else if (line.startsWith("*")) {
      isList = true;
      if (result.indexOf("<ul>") === -1) {
        result += "<ul>";
      }
      result += "<li>" + line.slice(1).trim() + "</li>";
    } else {
      if (isTable) {
        result += "</tbody></table>";
        isTable = false;
        tableHeaders = [];
      }
      if (isList) {
        result += "</ul>";
        isList = false;
      }
      result += line + "<br>";
    }
  }
  if (isTable) {
    result += "</tbody></table>";
  }
  if (isList) {
    result += "</ul>";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you would be better off just using a markdown parser and requiring users to use valid markdown if they want formatting. This is quite standard with multiple libraries available to help you on your way (ie this comment entry right now which **recognizes markdown**, but not some |random| |undocumented| formatting standard)

Comment: I agree with @pilchard, the heavy lifting of this type of thing has already been taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *how* you are determining how to tell what strings are what in terms of whether you will format as `table` or as `ol` you can use `split` and `regex` or a specific string to output an array of matching values that can then be formatted in specific functions.

So if your string includes a *specific string* that can be used as a *determining string* for the `.split` method, then split at that string and create an array that can be iterated over, each of these strings can then be evaluated and formatted according to their content.

My example uses a `forEach` loop that iterates over a node list of comments. Then I use a conditional to check if the `textContent` of each node includes a *specific string* or *identifier* that will be used to split these *comment strings* into their respective parts for further formatting. As each nodes textContent is evaluated, I check to see if the string includes a pipe followed by a space followed by another pipe --> `| |`, for example. This is used in the method I build and format the table in, so we can then run our buildTable method within that part of the conditional. The same logic can be applied to the orderedlist, it just depends on ***how*** you choose to split these strings and what ***means*** and ***methods*** you use to implement your formatting scheme --> `| |` for tables, then split the secondary string at a single pipe surrounded by spaces `|`, etc...

Hope this helps out. Let me know if there's anything not clear with the code or if you were looking for a different out come.

```js
const comments = document.querySelectorAll('.comments');

const buildOL = (arr) => {
  let output = '';
  arr.forEach((li, i) => i < 1 ? output += `<ol>${li.trim()}:` : output += `<li>${li.trim()}</li>`)
  output += '</ol>';
  return output;
}

const buildTable = (arr) => {
  let output = '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  arr.forEach(str => {
    output += `<tr>`;
    str.includes(' | ') ?
      str.split(' | ').forEach(col => output += `<td>${col.trim()}</td>`) :
      output += `<td colspan="2">${str.trim()}</td>`;
    output += `</tr>`;
  })
  output += `</table>`;
  return output;
}

comments.forEach(comment => {
  if (comment.textContent.includes('| |')) {
    comment.innerHTML = buildTable(comment.textContent.split(/\| \|/g))
  } else if (comment.textContent.match(/[0-9]. /)) {
    comment.innerHTML = buildOL(comment.textContent.split(/[0-9]. /))
  }
})
```

```css
.comments:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments">My favorite foods are 1. Pizza2. Burgers3. Tacos4. Sushi5. Pasta6. Fried chicken7. Ramen8. Curry9. Steak10. Ice cream</div>
<div class="comments">This is how I would rank the games. | | Rank | Game | | 1 | The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt | | 2 | Grand Theft Auto V | | 3 | Portal 2 | | 4 | Half-Life 2 | | 5 | Overwatch | | 6 | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive | | 7 | Doom (2016) | | 8 | Dark Souls III
  | | 9 | Divinity: Original Sin II | | 10 | Stardew Valley | |</div>
<div class="comments">This comment has no formatting what so ever</div>
```